# How can I prevent Internet Explorer from opening dragged files?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jsp

I have a JSP page which runs my application. But, when I drag a file from outside Internet Explorer into my application, Internet Explorer opens the file... :(

How can I avoid this?

Comment: That is a default browser behavior.. you cannot stop that!

Comment: but i heard that there are some drag events like (ondragover.. etc) can we solve the problem with that????

Comment: These events are thought if you drag something within the context of your page. You can't prevent the user from dragging files in to your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid dragging files into the internet explorer by using ondragover event of HTML. I tried in I.E 7.0 its working fine....:)

follow this code:

```
<body ondragover="return false"></body>
```